# Parse push notifications can take a long time to get delivered

Tags: android, push-notification, parse-platform

I am relatively new to Parse, and am finding that push notifications can take anywhere from being instantaneous, to taking a day or more to deliver. I can see the notifications registered in the admin panel immediately in every case, so issue is not on the send side.
I am developing on Android, but need the cross-platform capability of Parse so I can support iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Well you should prefer to use Google Cloud Messaging GCM for push notifications rather than using 3rd Parties like Parse etc. GCM is super fast and i am using in all my apps which are live.

Here are Good Links to Startoff with GCM

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Comment: Thanks Umer, but GCM is not cross platform. What I'm looking to do is get a cross-platform push notification going for my prototype, instead of implementing such a system myself.

Comment: Parse takes some times which is usually half an hour when i used it but the thing you are saying shouldnt be the case to take a day or so.

Comment: Sometimes it's instantaneous, but often it takes over an hour. (The last one I sent about an hour ago, and still has not arrived.)

Comment: @IstvanJonyer: I am using GCM in my app.When I do not get GCM push notifications on  time on my device,I toggle the internet data and see that most times I receive the notifications instantly.Have you observed this as well?

Answer (score 0):

I am aware about the parse notification.I am also having same problem,but the problem is because of the **Wifi**.

It means when you send an **parse notification** from panel it would take some time to deliver because of wifi is enable on your mobile.

So go with your mobile 3G connection it works within less time.

Comment: I never have wifi on, so this is not the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, Parse has a GCM handler, and it also needs to be added to the manifest. Otherwise Parse uses its own service, which can be very slow. Enabling GCM, I now have the notifications arriving in under 20 seconds.